# Using Two Video Cards (GTX 980 and Quadro 2000) SLI/Physx, or other options?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver, sli, physx

I have not asked a question here before and so I hope I am in the right spot.  I am having trouble getting my system to utilize both of my video cards (GTX 980 and Quadro 2000).  I would like the GTX 980 to be my primary and the Quadro to act as a supplement Physx Processor or boost to my rig in some way.

My Specs: Intel i5-4690K @ 3.5 GHz, 16 GB RAM

Video Cards: GTX 980, Quadro 2000

In the GeForce Experience program I am unable to see both video cards simultaneously.  In the device manager whenever I install (or reinstall) the drivers for either the device manager sees the other card but it says:

*Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43).*

I am not sure what I need to do to utilize both cards.  What steps do I need to take?

Notes:

The SLI option is not available in the NVIDIA Control Panel even though GTX 980 is SLI comptatible and CUDA are set to 'ALL'

GeForce Experience does not see other video card while the other is active

I have the latest drivers for both of the video cards and the latest version of Nvidia GeForce Experience  (this includes the latest Physx program)

If the SLI Physx card option is not viable what would be the best course of action?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you have in mind, but you can't run two different cards in SLI.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear.  My question is what is the best thing to do with this Quadro 2000 card to boost graphic and in-game performance?I read that you can use PhysX GPU acceleration in order to boost performance (nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/index.htm#mergedProjects/nvcpl/NVIDIA_Control_Panel.htm)  from To use PhysX GPU acceleration on SLI-ready systems.

Comment: PhysX will be in use if it's available, and it is on GTX 980. I don't think throwing in another card will make any difference.

Comment: @Tam - You can't use your Quadro with a GTX 980 to boot your in-game performance.  Quadro is not a gaming card.  Additionally, only mGPU DX12, would be helpful in a non-SLI configuration.

Comment: OK, thanks for the replies.  (PhysX is running on the GTX 980).  What do you suggest I do with this Quadro card then?... If I can do anything with it?